# ASP.Net Core Input Textbox and Receive Data with Jquery on Another DIV

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

Can someone teach me how to replace data with ajax, see image below

[image]

```
    Data Siswa Model
        public string NomorVA { get; set; }
        public string NamaSiswa { get; set; }
        public string Kelas { get; set; }

    form controller
                    public JsonResult Search(string VA) 
        {
            var namasiswa = from a in _context.DataSiswa
                           where a.NomorVA == VA
                            select new DataSiswa
                            {
                                NomorVA = a.NomorVA,
                                NamaSiswa = a.NamaSiswa,
                                Kelas = a.Kelas
                            };
            return Json(namasiswa);
        }
```

here my jquery in view

```
jquery ajax
var a = $("#va").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/PenerimaanKas/Search/",
                type: "GET",
                data: {VA:a},
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#nomorva").html(data.nomorVA);
                    $("#nama").html(data.nama);
                    $("#kelas").html(data.kelas);

                }
            });
```

div wont changed, if my jquery ajax wrong? can someone teach me or direct me for better solution? thanks

Comment: If you will only ever have a small amount of data (<10 records or so (your call as to how much)) then include it in the page and use javascript.  If it's an ever-increasing data-set then make an ajax call as you don't want to load all that data on each page load.

Comment: Thanks for reply, can you guide me how use javascript or jquery for it?

Comment: In this case, it looks like you're loading all 1000+ records to make that drop down - if you're only adding two more fields then include them in the drop down as `data-` and use javascript as it won't add that much.  If the "model" has a lot of other fields, then use ajax.  You should also consider making the drop down a search box with ajax as well.

Comment: "*can you guide me how use javascript or jquery*" - sorry, but no, that would be too broad for an SO question.  Don't mind adding a word of advice, but this is not a good subject for an SO question.  Have a read of [ask]

Comment: @freedomn-m okay, i changed my question. i research how to create ajax, but i have problem, my div wont changed. and i use network inspector, the inspector tell that ajax data success retrieved

Comment: Do you have more than one `#nomorva` ?  do `console.log($("#nomorva").length)`  also do `console.log(data, data.nomorVA)` inside the success.

Comment: i just have 1, consol says 1

Comment: What if you do `$("#nomorva").text("test")` - does that change it?  i.e. narrow down if it's the div / selector / data.

Comment: YES, it will change to test

Comment: So the selector is ok - are you hitting the `success:` callback?  If so, then it must be the data.  I'm guessing you're looking in the console for errors already.